# Using a PHP variable in Javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, function, variables, echo

Can I please have some help in using a PHP variable in some Javascript code.

I am wanting to pass a value to a Javascript function that is stored in a PHP variable.

Here is my code:

```
$UpdateText="updateReTotal(Tills,'pos_cash','{$till->till_id}');updateVariance('{$till->till_id}')";

echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
    , 'testFunctionForUpdateTotal(.$UpdateText.);'
    , '</script>';
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

```
$UpdateText="updateReTotal(Tills,'pos_cash','{$till->till_id}');updateVariance('{$till->till_id}')";

echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
    . 'testFunctionForUpdateTotal('.$UpdateText.');'
    . '</script>';
```

Your code would have worked if you were using double quotes (except for the two dots beside your variable, plus you need to escape the other double quotes), like this:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
 testFunctionForUpdateTotal($UpdateText)
 </script>";
```

But this does not work with single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language='javascript'>
function show(j)
{
alert(j);
}
</script>

<?php
$v = "a";
echo "<div onclick=\"show('".$v."',);return false;\">CLICK</div>";
?>
```